# Using multiple files in SwiftUI playground

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground, swift-structs

I am trying to use multiple files in SwiftUI playground. I added some code in a separate file in sources. I just want the sheet view to appear when the button is tapped. Even though I have made the struct public but I still get the error as " SecondView initializer is inaccessible due to internal protection level "

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingScene = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingScene.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingScene, content: {
           SecondView()  
        })
    }
}

//The code in source file

import SwiftUI

public struct SecondView: View{

    public var body: some View {

    Text("Second View")       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default initialiser (the one generated by the compiler, since you didn't declare one explicitly) is actually `internal`.

This is documented [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID20):

> A default initializer has the same access level as the type it initializes, unless that type is defined as public. For a type that’s defined as public, the default initializer is considered internal. If you want a public type to be initializable with a no-argument initializer when used in another module, you must explicitly provide a public no-argument initializer yourself as part of the type’s definition.

So you should do:

```
public struct SecondView: View{

    public init() { } // here!
    
    public var body: some View {

        Text("Second View")

    }
}
```